How can I load my own add-in when starting excel through powershell?
I have my own addin which features a new ribbon with lots of buttons and macros. We only use non macro excel files at work for a certain reason, hence the add in.
Since a few days now I'm opening excel through Powershell which does not start the add in.
I have read that you can change the loadBehaviour in regedit but this only works for COM add-ins.
Is it difficult to make your own COM add in?
Or is there another way to load the addin through either excel or powershell?
I havent really tried anything myself but I can't find something to try on this specific topic.
